# Post requests in python vs curl

Tags: python, curl

Can someone please suggest the correct syntax for calling the below using python?

```
curl "https://sometest.api.token" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}"
```

My attempt:

```
import requests
import json

credentials='1111'
secret='2222'

url = 'https://sometest.api.token'
body = {'client_credentials':credentials,'client_secret':secret}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), if you want to send some form-encoded data, you simply pass a dictionary to the data argument.

So you have to try:

```
import requests
import json

credentials='1111'
secret='2222'

url = 'https://sometest.api.token'
body = {'client_credentials':credentials, 'client_secret':secret}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

And also your parameters in python code are different from parameters in `curl`, maybe you have to check it.

Comment: Is the 'grant_type' in the curl example at all significant? I ask because I'm getting a 404 error with real credentials.

Comment: Yes the `grant_type` is likely important, and is not included in any of the Python code.

Comment: In general, yes, it is significant. I can not speak about your specific case, because I don't know what APIs you are using. But if your curl request works, you have to try using all parameters from it in `python-requests`. And `grant_type` is not the only difference: in the `curl` request I see `client_id` parameter while in python code I see `client_credentials` parameter.

Comment: Made an edit to the answer regarding the grant_type. Thank you